# How do I test ftplugin scripts efficiently

Tags: vimscript, filetype

Say I am writing a plugin and constantly editing scripts in `ftplugin`. How do I efficiently test the changes? I can't simply `source` the editted file because they are filetype-specific. For example, if there is a line

```
set buftype=nofile
```

in the script, and I `source` it, then whatever buffer I'm in will no longer be writable into a file...

I can open another vim instance to test the change, but that is not very efficient because I have to reopen one whenever I make changes to the ftplugin scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your script:

```
let b:undo_ftplugin='setlocal buftype='
```

When the `FileType` autocmd is fired, that variable will `execute`.  To trigger the `autocmd`, you could run `:set ft=whatever` to reload the `ftplugin` and `syntax` scripts.

While I'm tweaking an `ftplugin`, I usually don't want to save the changes made in a buffer during testing.  So, I just use `:e!` to reload the buffer since `:edit` effectively sets the detected `filetype`.

You can read more about this in `:h undo_ftplugin`.  To see exactly how this works, you can look at the script that loads your `ftplugin` script:

```
:e $VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin.vim
```